# How to get parameter in url (laravel 5.3)?

Tags: php, laravel, url, get, laravel-5.3

My url is like this : `http://localhost/mysystem/public/users/index/2016`

I want to get `2016`, because I need it. But, I'm confused

Is there any people who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your previous question I can see this method:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
```

And your route should look like this (partially taken from previous answer too):

```
Route::get('users/store/{year}', 'UserController@store')->name('users.store.year');
```

Note, that if you'll build `store` method with `Route::resource()`, you'll not be able to pass year through URL.

So, to make it work you need to set route and to change method to this:

```
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request, $year)
```

`$year` variable will have `2016` value.

Answer (score 0):

To get `2016`, you can use `$year = Request::segment(3);`.

Comment: There is exist error like this : `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::segment() should not be called statically`